# How to add titles on leaflet's layer control selection using react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, leaflet, bing-maps

I am using Leaflet JS with Bing map. I need to add titles on top of **Type 1 Layer** and **Category 1** overlays selection, displayed on right top of Map. I could not see any documentation for the same. Can someone help me.

My layers are,

**Base Layers:** Default and English

**Overlays:** Type 1 Layer, Type 2 Layer, Category 1, Category 2

**image** [image]

```
let type1Layer = L.layerGroup()
let type2Layer = L.layerGroup()
let category1 = L.layerGroup()
let category2 = L.layerGroup()
let overlays = {
            'Type1Layer': type1Layer, 
            'Type2Layer': type2Layer, 
            'Category1': category1, 
            'Category2': category2 
}
L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlays).addTo(myMap)
```

**Need to add titles Select Type and Select Category in layer selection window in map as below,**

**Select Type**

Type1Layer

Type2Layer

**Select Category**

Category1

Category2

Comment: Check this [example](https://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control/). Can you share your code?

Comment: @kboul I have updated code in my question.

Comment: So you want to invoke a function to change the language when switching between default and English and you also use react with leaflet, correct?

Comment: @kboul: I am using React with Leaflet. I need to add two titles in layer selection window. I have updated my question agin. Sorry for the updations.

Comment: You can use this [plugin](https://github.com/ismyrnow/leaflet-groupedlayercontrol) but it does not support space between words. that means you have to write `SelectType` instead of `Select Type` otherwise you will have to write your own custom plugin that extends `LayersControl`. If it fits your needs I can post an example

Comment: **Thanks a lot @kboul it satisfies my requirement !!!**

Comment: I posted an example. Please mark the answer as accepted if it helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  [leaflet-groupedlayercontrol](https://github.com/ismyrnow/leaflet-groupedlayercontrol) plugin to achieve the desired result.

When the component mounts you can separate your layer using `groupedOverlays` object by passing keys as Objects where their name would be your separation layer similar to a dictionary:

```
    useEffect(() => {
    var basemaps = {
      Grayscale: L.tileLayer(
        "http://{s}.tiles.wmflabs.org/bw-mapnik/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
        {
          maxZoom: 18,
          attribution:
            '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
        }
      ),
      Streets: L.tileLayer(
        "http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
        {
          maxZoom: 19,
          attribution:
            '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
        }
      )
    };

    var groups = {
      cities: new L.LayerGroup(),
      restaurants: new L.LayerGroup(),
      dogs: new L.LayerGroup(),
      cats: new L.LayerGroup()
    };

    L.marker([39.61, -105.02], { icon })
      .bindPopup("Littleton, CO.")
      .addTo(groups.cities);

    ...

    var map = L.map("map", {
      center: [39.73, -104.99],
      zoom: 10,
      layers: [basemaps.Grayscale, groups.cities]
    });

    // Overlay layers are grouped
    var groupedOverlays = {
      SelectType: {
        Type1Layer: groups.cities, // use your one
        Type2Layer: groups.restaurants // use your one
      },
      SelectCategory: {
        Category1: groups.dogs, // use your one
        Category2: groups.cats  // use your one
      }
    };

    // Use the custom grouped layer control, not "L.control.layers"
    L.control.groupedLayers(basemaps, groupedOverlays).addTo(map);
  }, []);

  return <div id="map" style={{ width: "600px", height: "400px" }} />;
```

Replace your layers with the ones in the exampel and you should be good

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-add-titles-on-leaflet-js-layer-selection-using-react-l0qdj?file=/src/App.js:482-2828)